# I cannot see the Rules event "Page is going to be viewed"

Tags: 7, rules

I am looking for rules event "Page is going to be viewed" but I cannot see it; is there something I am missing?

I'm using rules 7.23, I have panels enabled, and I want to use it to redirect authenticated users to another page when they click on the front page.

Comment: What makes you think there should be a "Page is going to be viewed" rule? Have you seen it used somewhere before?

Comment: Also, I removed the request for code (we don't have a code-writing service here). If you have problems with code that you've written, please edit the question to add that in, describe what you expect to happen, and what actually happens. Thanks

Comment: If you make your requirement clear enough, we can try to suggest whether it's possible by rules or not. It's not only event but sometimes condition also make some other event do what we want like - Viewing a page & it has certain path etc..

Comment: The rules event was mentioned on this post though for drupal 6: https://drupal.org/node/514824